# IOS UIWebView is not loading the full website

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

i am learning iOS. i am trying to load a website in the UIWebView. The webpage is loading but the web view is not loading the full website. Instead the web view loads partial page of the website. Here is the code
what have i done wrong??

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    webView.frame = self.view.frame
    let url = "http://www.tradiestart.com.au"
    let requestUrl = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestUrl!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: ya..wait.. i'll post it

Comment: maybe implement the delegate and see if it finished loading?

Comment: if we use delegate will it load the entire website??

Comment: @kdogisthebest i don't get the solution. can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*choice -1*

```
 webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

> if it is not work try choice no -2

*choice -2*

```
 webView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
 webView.center = self.view.center
 webView.scalesPageToFit = true
```

*choice -3*

```
 webView.frame =CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height)

 or 

    webView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
```

additional [reference1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5885), [reference2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UICatalog_WebViewController_swift.html)

here I attached the [sample project](https://www.sendspace.com/file/snt7cv)

the project output

[image]

Comment: @GaneshKumar -- can you show the output of the screen , it is easy to optimize your answer

Comment: given that the scroll is enabled and the frame is already set to the uiviiew this wouldn't change anything

Comment: here it is.. i have split the output of the simulator into two screenshots.. but if you see the website tradiestart.com.au.. the output doesn't have the full website loaded

Comment: then your page load perfectly , problem is web view frame

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Nope.. still having same problem..i have used pin to set the ui web view..is that the problem??

Comment: pin means setting up the web view's size to the device in the UI design.. top, left,right and bottom sizes.. is that the problem?

Comment: are you using auto layout then change/update  the constraint else my coding is working perfectly

Comment: hiyiyo.. aala vidunga saamy.. k badhil sollunga.. web page yaen fulla load aaga matengudhu?

Comment: check the updated answer, in here I attached the sample project , it working in all devices and all orientations

Comment: u didn't get me.. did u visit the website? it has many items below the "Get Started" title in that website.. those contents are not available once i run in the simulator

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik still i don't get the full website

Comment: your website is responsive , based on devices it automatically adjust the size on the web pages, if you want to get the more details about your website' click the settings  menu in right side top corner,

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong at all. There is no problem whatsoever with the code. I'm not sure why you split the screenshot but the website has a mobile version and that's what your seeing. They purposely made it look like that. They scale it to the devices width and remove elements if needed.

[image: Site mentioned in code]

Comment: did the website load fully?

Comment: yes, the website just looks different on mobile devices. it's responsive.

Comment: so what have i done wrong? the web view should scroll down to show the entire  website. instead it doesn't show the full website

Comment: Try calling `webView.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: so you are saying that there is no problem in the code.. but why that website is not loading fully like we load in the browser?

Comment: There are two things. 1st it's loading the mobile version that has somethings stripped away and the menu condensed. 2nd if you are unable to scroll down then either `userInteractionEnabled = false` or scroll is disabled or some other view is in the way.

Comment: Check your xib interface file and see if one of those properties is checked on the right sidebar.

Comment: @ryanfowler can i use swift data for an existing database